# Magento 1.9 : Increase captcha character length

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha

How to increase captcha character length in magento 1.9?

I do that using **System -> Advanced -> Admin -> CAPTCHA -> Number of Symbols**

But, there are no any effect in captcha character length.

I want to set captcha character length between 7 to 8.

Comment: I have tried it in Magento 1.9.3.8. It is working fine. I have tried for 7-8 and 9-10 ranges.

Comment: Have you made any changes in the default captcha functionality?

Comment: In which file have you changed ?

Comment: I made changes in the settings only. No files changes done.

Comment: But, I also changed via settings but, no any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using this both option :

1 ) Go to this below location and change value of Number of Symbols.

> System -> Advanced -> Admin -> CAPTCHA -> Number of Symbols

2) Go to this below file path

> /app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/Config.xml

Add your length in  tag.

For admin login forgot password captcha :

```
<admin>
            <captcha>
                <type>zend</type>
                <enable>0</enable>
                <font>linlibertine</font>
                <mode>after_fail</mode>
                <forms>backend_forgotpassword</forms>
                <failed_attempts_login>3</failed_attempts_login>
                <failed_attempts_ip>1000</failed_attempts_ip>
                <timeout>7</timeout>
                <length>6-7</length>
                <symbols>ABCDEFGHJKMnpqrstuvwxyz23456789</symbols>
                <case_sensitive>0</case_sensitive>
                <always_for>
                    <backend_forgotpassword>1</backend_forgotpassword>
                </always_for>
            </captcha>
        </admin>
```

For customer user forgot password :

```
<customer>
            <captcha>
                <type>zend</type>
                <enable>0</enable>
                <font>linlibertine</font>
                <mode>after_fail</mode>
                <forms>user_forgotpassword</forms>
                <failed_attempts_login>3</failed_attempts_login>
                <failed_attempts_ip>1000</failed_attempts_ip>
                <timeout>7</timeout>
                <length>6-7</length>
                <symbols>ABCDEFGHJKMnpqrstuvwxyz23456789</symbols>
                <case_sensitive>0</case_sensitive>
                <always_for>
                    <user_create>1</user_create>
                    <user_forgotpassword>1</user_forgotpassword>
                    <guest_checkout>1</guest_checkout>
                    <register_during_checkout>1</register_during_checkout>
                </always_for>
            </captcha>
        </customer>
```